# Filling in and adding the data with the rows in Panda's dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have the following dataframe (df1):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data={'ID':[1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2],
'city':['A',0,0,'C','D','E',0,'F']}
df1=pd.DataFrame(data)
df1.replace(0,np.nan,inplace=True)

df1
```

The display of df1 should look like this.

[image]

The expected table that I expect should look like this.

```
 import pandas as pd
 import numpy as np

 data={'ID':[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2],
 'city':['A','C','D','C','D','C','D','E','F','F']}
 df2=pd.DataFrame(data)
 df2.replace(0,np.nan,inplace=True)

 df2
```

[image]

My issue is how to create df2 (the expected table) from df1. I have tried bfill().

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data={'ID':[1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2],
'city':['A',0,0,'C','D','E',0,'F']}
df3=pd.DataFrame(data)
df3.replace(0,np.nan,inplace=True)

df3

df3.bfill()
```

The result from bfill() gave the following table.

[image]

but the command fills in only the value in NaN. For instance, the  first two NaN(s) of ID1  were filled in with 'C' only and it  does  not add  the additional rows to the dataframe,which  is not what I am keen on.

My question is how to construct df2(2nd table) from  df1?  Any comments/suggestions?

Thank you.

Comment: You said you want to fill NaNs and additional columns. Can you explain a little bit more how do you want to add the columns?

Comment: From df1, I  want  to  add a block of 'C'  and  'D'  in the  index  [3 , 4]  to NaN in  index 1 and NaN  in index 2.  The  expected outcome should  look  like  df2. That  is, index  1,2  are  filled with 'C' and 'D'. Index  3,4 are filled with 'C' and 'D'.Thank you.

Comment: Ok, and why index 6 is filled only with `F`?

Comment: because I want  to fill in only 'F' to index 6.  The issue is that, for ID1, I need to fill in NaNs with  a block of  'C' and 'D'  and, for ID2, I need to fill only one value, which is 'F', to NaN in index 6.

Comment: The question is does your data have multiple nan blocks? Or does it have a nan block at the bottom of the ID block? In which case, what would you expect?

Comment: For ID1, it  is multiple  NaN blocks , but,for ID2, it is only a NaN. Thank you.

Comment: by `blocks` I mean `consecutive rows`. In your sample, both ID's have only one NaN block.

Comment: Let's put it  this way. For  ID1,  I want to fill  2 values('C'  and  'D') into each  NaN and this  will  expand  the rows ID1's dataframe while, for  ID2,  I want  to fill only 1 value into NaN,which  does not affect the number  of  rows of dataframe.

Answer (score 2):

For the sample data, that means making a merge on ID between the `NaN` rows and the non-NaN rows that come after it:

```
nans = df1['city'].isna()
blocks = nans.groupby(df1['ID']).cumsum()
    
(pd.concat([df1[blocks==0], 
            df1[(~nans) & blocks.gt(0)]
                .merge(df1.loc[nans,['ID']].reset_index(),on='ID')
           ])
   .sort_values(['ID','index'],na_position='first')
   [df1.columns]
)
```

Output:

```
   ID city
0   1    A
0   1    C
2   1    D
1   1    C
3   1    D
5   2    E
4   2    F
```

This, however, might produce a non-expected output if your data looks like this:

```
data={'ID':[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2],
      'city':['A',np.nan,np.nan,'C','D',np.nan,np.nan,'E',np.nan,'F']}
```

In which case, you'd get 4 `C` and 4 `D`.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you have *fixed requirement* how `ID 1` and `ID 2` should replace `NaN`s:

```py
to_replace = {1: ['C', 'D'], 2: ['F']}

df1.loc[df1['city'].isna(), 'city'] = df1.loc[df1['city'].isna(), 'ID'].map(to_replace)
print(df1.explode('city'))
```

Prints:

```
   ID city
0   1    A
1   1    C
1   1    D
2   1    C
2   1    D
3   1    C
4   1    D
5   2    E
6   2    F
7   2    F
```